# How to understand an R GLM model formulated as y ~ day.of.week+hour+minute?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I am converting an R script to Python. The developer uses an R GLM, formulated as y ~ day.of.week+hour+minute.
I find it confusing on the one hand: these factors are nested, they seem written as independent. On the other hand, I think the intention is to predict y as a weekly recurring pattern, in which the minute 11:00 to 11:01 on Wednesdays are similar.
Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a model tries to detect a linear kind of relationship between each of the covariates and a response. Linearity is one of the assumptions that should hold before any linear model is being built.

To put it in intuition, the model will measure if **y** depends linearly on the week day: negatively or positively; if **y** depends on a day hour (it can be negatively or positively as well), and the same for minutes. Please note that there are no interacting terms in the equation (like **hour * minute**), which would allow for a dependency based on both covariates at the same time.

The Gauss-Markov assumptions behind OLS linear models (generalized or not) state that there should not be a perfect collinearity, but some degree of dependence between the covariates is possible.

Comment: Thank you. So the prediction for the minute 11:00 to 11:01 is not in any way based on the patterns for the other minutes, right? In this (nested) case, would you think, the Gauss-Markov assumptions hold?

Comment: If a GLM model's coefficient for the minute is significantly different from zero (which you can check by looking at the t-statistic or p-value), then it does not matter which hour it is and which day of week it is. It only matters that minutes inside any time interval influence linearly the output variable. And by the way hour, minute, and day will not be dependent at all since all of their combinations are equally possible (you cannot expect that at hour 15 you will see more seconds > 30 than at hour 4, if not explicitly designed by experiment). The Gauss-Markov assumptions hold.